# Ubuntu 14.04 install on usb using mac

Tags: usb, 14.04

I'm having trouble with this step in creating the usb boot:

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN
```

I've also tried unmounting the disk from the disk utility window, but when going on to the next step:

`sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m`

I get an error of:

`"No such file or directory"`

Answer (score 0):

> sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m

The problem is you need to replace N in the above.

From [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X:](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) "Run diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN (replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2)."